# FaceBook checkin in IOS 6 and IOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, ios5, ios6

I have some predefined location of different stores.I want to checkin to these locations through my IOS app.How can I do it?

Here is the code I used for IOS 5

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [SBJSON new];
NSMutableDictionary *coordinatesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", latitude], @"latitude",
                                              [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", longitude], @"longitude",
                                              nil];
NSString *coordinates = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:coordinatesDictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [[placesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"], @"place", //The PlaceID
                               coordinates, @"coordinates", // The latitude and longitude in string format (JSON)
                               @"Testing check in", @"message", // The status message
                               nil];
//                                       tags, @"tags", // The user's friends who are being checked in

[[appDelegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/checkins" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate: self];
// Deselect
```

Comment: -1; do you have any code to show off?  what have you tried so far?

Comment: i am able to checkin to predefined locations that are shown in placepicker using ios sdk.But i am not able to checkin to custom places.